# Angular 8 routlerlink works only after page reload

Tags: angular8, angular-routerlink

After a successful login, it is navigated to the dashboard URL. From that menu, links aren't working even though URL is changing in the address bar. router link in the menu is working when we forcefully do a page reload in the browser. otherwise, nothing is happening. There is no error in the console as well. The code is given below.

login navigation which works currently

```
    this.usermanagementService.login('login', {username: userName, password})
    .subscribe(message => {
        this.jwt.saveToken(message.data.token);      

        if (window.localStorage.getItem('locale') === null) {
          window.localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
// More lines which handles the error section
```

The app menu html

```
 <div *ngIf="m.submenus?.length > 0" class="collapse" id="{{ m.name }}" aria-expanded="false">
             <ul class="flex-column pl-2 nav submenu-dark">
                <li *ngFor="let secondlevel of m.submenus" class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link collapsed text-truncate" routerLink="{{ secondlevel.slug }}"><span>{{ secondlevel.name }}</span></a>

                </li>
             </ul>
      </div>
```

Currently routerlink works  after we do a forceful redirect instead of angular router navigation. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue with the following changes in `app.component`

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'; else loginTemplateName" id="wrapper" class="toggled container-margin-fix">
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    <app-footer></app-footer> 
</div> 
<ng-template #loginTemplateName>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    <app-footer></app-footer> 
</ng-template>
```

Inside the `app-menu` and `app-footer` there is an `*ngIf` checking whether it is not the login url. We need to add `app-menu` container in both cases in the `app.component.html` then only it will work eventhough it is hidden inside `app-menu`. Earlier it was just `<router-outlet>` only for the login route in the a`app.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

Put the navigation URL in if a condition or in else condition.
Or another problem is your menu component did not get which user is login, so you should try event emit when user login and subscribe into menu component and set condition related to login user.